# How to add conditions to my recorded macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I have recorded the macro below, which is used to auto-transfer data that I enter into one worksheet to another worksheet when I run the macro. At present, I would have to record a macro for each new worksheet in this workbook and run each separate macro depending upon which sheet I need the new data transferred to. I would like to know how to add conditions to this macro that will automatically decide which worksheet to send the new data to, based on what text is in column G of the original worksheet. There are four different text phrases that might be contained in column G. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub over_90_days()
'
' over_90_days Macro
' transfer info from all terms to over 90 days sheet
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
End Sub


Sub update()
'
' update Macro
' move new data to a different worksheet
'

'
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Name, Last]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("A74:B74").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("90 DAYS OR LESS").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("ALL TERMS").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("90 DAYS OR LESS").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("ALL TERMS").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("90 DAYS OR LESS").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("ALL TERMS").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("90 DAYS OR LESS").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

So here's my second less that glorious attempt:

```
Sub update()

Set MainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ALL TERMS")
Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TERM PRE OJT")
Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TERM POST OJT")
Set Sheet3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("90 DAYS OR LESS")
Set Sheet4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OVER 90 DAYS")
Dim Rnge2 As Range
Set Rnge2 = "A2"

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 50
MyValue = MainSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value

If MyValue = "orientation only" Then

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)).Copy
Sheet1.Select
Rnge2.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select       'move down one row

ElseIf MyValue = "ojt only" Then

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)).Copy
Sheet2.Select
Rnge2.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

ElseIf MyValue = "90 days or less" Then

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)).Copy
Sheet3.Select
Rnge2.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

ElseIf MyValue = "over 90 days" Then

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4)).Copy
Sheet1.Select
Rnge2.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End If
Next

End Sub
```

it doesn't work, and I have no idea why.

Comment: It sounds like all you need is a Select Case expression that looks at the contents of G to determine which sheet to paste to.  Did you try that?

Comment: I did not try a Select Case expression, but I'm about to google it now, Lol. Thanks.

Comment: When trying to see what is the problem of a code, you have to `debug`. Debug in VBA is easy, you can press `F8` to execute your code line by line and see which line brings a problem. I'll update my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select sheets like this:

```
dim MyWorksheet as Worksheet
set MyWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("the name of the sheet you want")
```

So, you can set `MyWorksheet` as any sheet you want in the code using the name of that sheet:

```
dim MyWorksheet1 as Worksheet
set MyWorksheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("the name a sheet")

dim MyWorksheet2 as Worksheet
set MyWorksheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("the name of second sheet")
```

Now, you can get any cell in a sheet like:

```
dim MyCell as Range, MyCell2 as Range, MyCell3 as Range
set MyCell = MyWorksheet1.Range("G1") // gets G1
set MyCell2 = MyWorksheet1.Range("G:G") // gets the entire G column
set MyCell3 = MyWorksheet1.Cells(2,2) // gets B2
```

You can see what is the value in the cell with:

```
MyCell.Value
```

And you can set the value of a cell:

```
MyCell.Value = "The Value I want" //a text
MyCell.Value = 2 //a number
MyCell.Value = MyCell2.Value //the value of another cell
```

With this, you can play around and create your own code, selecting the cells you desire and transfering to the sheets you desire.

If you are not used to programming, search for tutorials on `loops`, `if statements`, `select case statements` for VBA.

All those `selection` that appear in the recorded macro can be replaced with a `Range` like the ones I showed above, unless you really want to get the selected cell, then use selection as recorded.

The `copy` and `paste commands` will work for the worksheets as shown above too. But sometimes it's better to transfer values via code with the `Range.Value` (this avoids copying format and forumlas, and is quicker).

---

An example:

Column G in MainSheet contains 3 rows, I'll copy them to Sheet1 or Sheet2 depending on the value in the cell:

```
dim MainSheet as Worksheet, Sheet1 as Worksheet, Sheet2 as Worksheet
set MainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MainSheet")
set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The name of sheet1")
set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("The name of sheet2")    

dim i as integer
for i = 1 to 3    'this is a loop that will run three times with i from 1 to 3
    dim MyValue as variant
    MyValue = MainSheet.Cells(i,7).Value    'i is the row / 7 is G

    'check the value of a cell in row "i" and column G
    if MyValue = "the value I want to go to sheet 1" then
        Sheet1.Cells(i,7).Value = MyValue    'copy to sheet 1 same row and column, but you can change that
    else                                   'if value is not that one I expected
        Sheet2.Cells(i,7).Value = MyValue    'copy to sheet 2....
    end if                                  'this ends the if part of the code
next 'this ends the loop part of the code
```

---

Looking at your second attempt:

In your case, I believe `Set Rnge2 = "A2"` is the first problem. A `Range` is an object you must retrieve from a sheet: `Set Rnge2 = MainSheet.Range("A2")`

In code, I always avoid methods that use the interface, like copy/paste and active cell, these are slow and brings more concerns to care about.

So I'd suggest you do the following:

```
'this forces me to declare all vars. It's a personal preference
'this way I don't have any var with an unidentified type
Option Explicit

Sub update()

    'declare every sheet because I used option explicit
    'option explicit obliges that we declare everything, I prefer it this way to avoid having unknown vars in the code
    Dim MainSheet As Worksheet, Sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet, Sheet3 As Worksheet, Sheet4 As Worksheet
    Set MainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ALL TERMS")
    Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TERM PRE OJT")
    Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TERM POST OJT")
    Set Sheet3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("90 DAYS OR LESS")
    Set Sheet4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OVER 90 DAYS")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim R1 As Integer, R2 As Integer, R3 As Integer, R4 As Integer
    Dim CurrentCell As Range
    Dim MyValue As String

    'keeping one row per sheet in order to move down separately
    R1 = 2  'start row in sheet1
    R2 = 2 'start row in sheet2
    R3 = 2 'start row in sheet3
    R4 = 2 'start row in sheet4

    For i = 1 To 26

        'Using a current cell in MainSheet, this will move down at the end of this loop
        Set CurrentCell = MainSheet.Cells(i, 7)

        'Taking value from the current cell
        MyValue = LCase(CurrentCell.Value)

        If MyValue = "orientation only" Then

            'Created a sub that avoids repeating all the code four times
            'copies the row i from main sheet to row R1 in Sheet1
            Call CopyTo(MainSheet, i, Sheet1, R1)
            R1 = R1 + 1 'move down one row'

        ElseIf MyValue = "ojt only" Then

            Call CopyTo(MainSheet, i, Sheet2, R2)
            R2 = R2 + 1 'move down one row'

        ElseIf MyValue = "90 days or less" Then

            Call CopyTo(MainSheet, i, Sheet3, R3)
            R3 = R3 + 1 'move down one row'

        ElseIf MyValue = "over 90 days" Then

            Call CopyTo(MainSheet, i, Sheet4, R4)
            R4 = R4 + 1 'move down one row'

        Else
            MsgBox "Cell G" & Trim(Str(i)) & " has an invalid value"
        End If

        'move down the current cell in main sheet
        Set CurrentCell = CurrentCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next

End Sub

Sub CopyTo(MainSheet As Worksheet, MainRow As Integer, TargetSheet As Worksheet, TargetRow As Integer)

    Dim LineValue As Variant

    'take all values from cell "Ai" to "Ei" in MainSheet
    LineValue = MainSheet.Range(MainSheet.Cells(MainRow, 1), MainSheet.Cells(MainRow, 5)).Value

    'puts this value in a same size range in target sheet
    TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, 1), TargetSheet.Cells(TargetRow, 5)).Value = LineValue

End Sub
```

Comment: I will be trying these suggestions. Thank you for your help, I will post when I figure out my code.

Comment: I believe I am following this example. How do i change it so that instead of running 3 times, it will keep running until it gets to an empty cell (or the end of column G?)

Comment: And also, if the first row I want the code to run on is row 3, do I have to designate that somehow?

Comment: Here's what I attempted:

Comment: From your attempt, it was possible to make this code... I'm not sure if it's exactly how you expected, but now you can adjust it at ease. (Please notice that this code will write over any data you have in Sheets 1 to 4 - If you want to avoid this, you can search for how to find the last row in a sheet to start writing below it, than your `R1` to `R4` vars should start from that row instead of row 2)

Comment: Wow, @Daniel that is fantastic! As you can probably tell, I'm rather new to writing code. I just tried this and it worked beautifully. I'll need to tweek it slightly to include only certain columns to be copied to worksheets 1 through 4, but I am really grateful for your help!